# How to slice rows from two pandas dataframes then merge them with some other value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two pandas dataframes and two indexes, and one datetime variable. What I would like to do is:

1. slice the dataframes with the indexes, then I got two rows.
2. combine the two rows to one row.
3. add the variable to the row.
4. then I can get new indexes and datetime values to form more rows, and assemble the rows to a new dataframe.

Example:

df1:

```
    A   B
0   0   10
1   1   11
2   2   12
3   3   13
4   4   14
5   5   15
6   6   16
7   7   17
8   8   18
9   9   19
```

df2:

```
    C   D
0   10  110
1   11  111
2   12  112
3   13  113
4   14  114
5   15  115
6   16  116
7   17  117
8   18  118
9   19  119
```

index: 3, 5, datetime: `datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 10, 16, 53, 52, 760014)`

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   time
0   3   13  15  115 20180810-16:53:52:760014
... # More rows when there's more indexes and datetimes
```

Comment: what's the use of df2 in this?

Comment: Hi krishna, the columns C and D are extracted from df2 by the index 5. it is a bit misleading, I'll edit the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
index = [3,5]
data = np.r_[df1.iloc[index[0]].values,df2.iloc[index[1]].values]
df = pd.DataFrame([data],columns = list('ABCD'))
dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 10, 16, 53, 52, 760014)
df['date'] = dt
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   date
0   3   13  15  115 2018-08-10 16:53:52.760014
```